# Branching Strategy - Maintaining Multiple Releases

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, merge, branch

For years we've been using TFS (TFVC) as our version control system. We will probably migrate to git anyway, but I am trying to figure out

1) Is there a more sensible branching strategy/model than the one we're currently using, specifically for maintaining multiple production releases (typically for several different customers)?

2) With regards to 1), are there specific benefits to git over TFVC?

What we do today is actually quite simple:

```
Mainline ----------------------------------------------------
             |          |          |          |          |         
        Release 3  Release 4  Release 5  Release 6  "Release" 7
```

All releases have their own branch on mainline, even development work for future versions is done an a "future" release branch. In the above, "Release 7" is work in progress and have not been released yet.

Under each of these branches might be further sub-branches such as feature branches to isolate work and to keep the release branches stable, but I don't think it's important for this discussion.

Whenever there is a change in one of these release branches, it has to eventually merged to mainline and from there to all future releases to avoid regressions for a customer going from, say, Release 3 to Release 5.

In practice, changes to these "old" branches are not only small bugfixes, but might be larger features that a customer on Release 3 has requested and it is developed in Release 3 and the customer receives a new version of Release 3. Eventually the feature will be merged to mainline and from there to all future releases.

Since merging always happens from every branch over mainline to every newer branch, this effectively means that mainline is mostly identical with the newest release branch.

And this is the first headache: There is something unnatural (and indeed it causes problems from time to time) about merging from an old version 3 over mainline which is very new and then from mainline to also old version 5. There might be large and breaking changes when comparing version 3 to version 6 for instance. It would be much more natural to merge directly from Release 3 to Release 5, but TFVC doesn't support that. You can only merge to your immediate parent (or children). Does git have the same limitation?

Another problem is that it is not possible in TFVC to cherry pick merge an entire feature if it's changesets are not in one consecutive, unbroken block in the history. If changesets from some other feature are interleaved, you either have to merge each consecutive sub-block the features changesets or you have to merge everything from the source branch to the destination branch. And doing multiple cherry pick merges is not always possible either because all changesets might be needed for building or unit testing to even be possible. I can see why TFVC has this limitation because a newer changeset of the feature might build upon the older, interleaved changeset from another feature. So it might not even make sense to just merge the changesets originally from this feature. In practice, we tend to merge everything ready for merge, it has to be merged anyway at some point. How does git compare in this regard?

What would be a sensible branching strategy/model for our case and will migration to git help us?

Comment: did you check git flow ? http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Yes, I have read about, but everything I find seems centered on having only one master to release from. Someone mentioned support branches which might be something like what we need, but it also seemed like an esoteric feature and where you're not supposed to merge your fixes back to the master, which I don't understand. How do people generally maintain multiple release branches?

Comment: master is just the default branch but it is just a branch, its up to you to use it or not. For some project, I do not have master at all, I go straight creating branch by product name. you can have multiple release branches. There's no concept of [support branches](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/#support-branches) its up to your flow to define the branch the way you want. Also when you release, there's nothing that tell you must release from master, you can release from any branch and you can tag this release against this branch

Comment: I get that, you can sort of work that way in TFVC too if you want. But the problem remains: If you make a fix/change to an old version 3, how do you make sure that this fix/change is then contained in all future releases, also newer versions of old releases, such as hotfixes in version 5?

Comment: If you're going to fix something in old version 3, first thing (git rules) is to start a new branch from this point, fix that; then merge back to the original branch - then if you want this fix in other branch, the best is to cherry-pick this particular commit on the branch where it is needed

Comment: So if a year goes by between fixing something in version 3 and fixing something in version 5, you have to at this late stage figure out which earlier commits/changesets from earlier branches you want to merge into version 5? That seems dangerous. Humans make mistakes, it might be hard to figure out at this point. Also, you can't test it before this late point. In our model, as soon as someone has fixed something in version 3, it gets merged to versions 4, 5, 6 etc, and it is then tested again in these versions to make sure there are no regressions.

Answer (score 0):

There are large differences between TFVC (CVCS) and git (DVCS). 
And the simple workflow for git usuallyas below:

- `feature` branches is usually created from `develop` branch for developing new features or fixing bugs. They are usually shorting living branch. After a feature or bug is finished, it should merge into `develop` branch.
- `develop` branch is used for all developers merge their works (features and bugs) in it.
- `master` as the main branch which manage the stable code for your project. QA team can test for merging `develop` branch into `master` branch.

So the branch structure looks like:

```
...-----------------   master
           /   ... /
...----------------    develop
     \  /   \   /
      --     ---
  feature1    featuren
```

Comment: I understand that. But in our case, we have multiple master branches so to speak. We also isolate development with feature branches and so on. But in your graph, you only have one branch that you can release from and that is master. In our case, we have to be able to release from several "master" branches, one for each release. And on the other hand, these multiple master branches are not independent, changes made in earlier versions should be merged forward to newer versions to avoid regressions. We can't be the only team in the world maintaining multiple versions?

Comment: I guess it's like Microsoft having to maintain both Word 2010, Word 2013 and Word 2016. If a bug is fixed in Word 2010, you have to merge it to Word 2013 and Word 2016 if the fix is relevant there also.

Comment: That's the difference between TFVC and git. As you showed in your graph, for TFVC, you need to have many release branches (1~7), but for git, you just need a release branch. More detailes, you can refer git book: branching and merging https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging. And for git, usually the main branch is called master and it's a default branch, And based on your description, master seems work  as feature branches. But it doesn't matter since it's just caused by different names of branches we called.